# \pdfminorversion on the command line?

Tags: macros, pdftex, line, command-line

Is it possible to set the pdfminorversion on the commandline when calling pdflatex, instead of using \pdfminorversion=... in the tex file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your LaTeX source  file is named `file.tex`:

```
pdflatex "\pdfminorversion=5 \input file.tex"
```