# How to set \pdfminorversion in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

How do I set `\pdfminorversion=6` in `org-mode`?

I don't know how to put that line before anything else in the resulting `.tex` file.

This is the workaround I am using now: [\pdfminorversion on the command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462661/pdfminorversion-on-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`org-mode` manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-header-and-sectioning.html):

> ```
> #+LATEX_CLASS: article
> #+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper]
> #+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xyz}
>
> * Headline 1
>   some text
> * Headline 2
>   some more text
> ```

So you can do

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \pdfminorversion=6
```

You may want to research how to ensure that org-mode uses pdftex (it did on my system by default), or use an `\ifPDFTeX ... \fi` block.

Comment: You are absolutely right. If my memory doesn't fail, I remember having tried this with a previous versions of `texlive` and getting an error because the `pdfminorversion` definition was not **before** the `documentclass`. This approach (your answer) certainly leaves the definition **after** the `documentclass`, that's why before your answer I didn't even bother. However, upon actually trying it, I don't get the error anymore, it works like a charm. Thanks!